# Exception for NSKeyedUnarchiver, but everything works

Tags: objective-c, nskeyedarchiver, nscoder, nskeyedunarchiver

I'm getting odd exception:

```
-[NSKeyedUnarchiver initForReadingWithData:]: data is empty; did you forget to send -finishEncoding to the NSKeyedArchiver?
```

when deserializing object that was previously archived with `NSKeyedArchiver` *and* transferred over the network. Everything works properly though (the data is the same), but this exception kept logging is annoying. Exception does not occur, however, when I serialize-deserialize locally.

Here's how I serialize object:

```
NSData *payload = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:object];
```

Here's how I deserialize object:

```
NCNamespaceObject *object = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:payload];
```

Here's object's `encodeWithCoder:` method (`super`'s method is empty):

```
-(void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aCoder
{
    [super encodeWithCoder:aCoder];
    [aCoder encodeObject:self.text forKey:@"text"];
}
```

And finally, here's the object's initializer:

```
-(instancetype)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    if (self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder])
    {
        _text = [aDecoder decodeObjectForKey:@"text"];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Not sure why it keeps posting this error...

Comment: For deserialization, where are you getting `payload` from? (Disk, the web, etc.) If you log its value, what do you see?

Comment: @ItaiFerber i transfer over the network. logged payloads - exactly the same!

Comment: What is the data that is printed? Perhaps we can diagnose based on that.

Comment: not sure how that might help, as they are both identical http://pastebin.com/FTEd09TB